# Validation accuracy does not make sense

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

My data set is the following: 
Training set: 5589 images
Validation set: 1398 images
Test set: 1996 images
Size: 1156,256,1
The problem is a binary classification problem. I got some results (reaching ~83% accuracy in test set) using hot-encoded target arrays [0,1],[1,0]. Realizing how stupid this was I changed target arrays to binary form [0] or [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWGJb.png) and changing categorical_crossentropy to binary crossentropy.

With this approach the validation accuracy gets stuck at 82.05% no matter what learning rate I use and the training accuracy gets stuck at 25.80%. Of course, this has no sense, and the in the test set accuracy is around ~30%.

Why can be this happening? I checked both training data and metadata and they are correct. I post my code below.

```python
inp = Input(shape=input_shape)
out = Conv2D(16, (5, 5),activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(inp)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)

out = Conv2D(32, (3, 3),activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)

out = Conv2D(32, (3, 3),activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)

out = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = Conv2D(64, (3, 3),activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)

out = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = Conv2D(128, (3, 3),activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)

out = Conv2D(256, (3, 3),activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)
out = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation = 'relu',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), padding='same')(out)
out = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(out)

out = Flatten()(out)
out = Dropout(0.5)(out)
dense1 = Dense(1, activation="softmax")(out)
model = Model(inputs = inp, outputs = dense1)
```

And the epochs look like this:
[Epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWGJb.png)

Comment: last dense layer `activation='sigmoid'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your last activation from softmax to sigmoid, like

```
dense1 = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(out)
```

and try lowering your learning rate

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001), loss='binary_crossentropy',  metrics=['accuracy'])
```